# How to request "System Audio Recording Only" permission? on macOS Sonoma

Tags: screencapturekit

I notice from macOS Sonoma System Settings, we have "Screen & System audio Recording". I'm an macOS app developer and want to request only Audio permission, I browse the document for a while and WWDC code demo, but still have no idea of how to request "System Audio Recording Only" permission? All the demo and doc I can find is request "Screen Recording & System Audio"

WWDC demo code:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screencapturekit/capturing_screen_content_in_macos

I try to run capturing_screen_content_in_macos demo and try to comment out

```
                try stream?.addStreamOutput(streamOutput, type: .screen, sampleHandlerQueue: videoSampleBufferQueue)
```

Comment: this might be better posted on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question?

Comment: @dimicountzero nope, no one reply :-(